# Change activity to AppCompatActivity leads to program failure- Eclipse(Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am four month new to Eclipse and Android. While I am creating a new project with default setting - empty activity.I found in the Manifest file, it extends activity. However, I want to have an actionbar by changing the activity to AppCompatActivity. Although there does not show an error  directly, the program will stop immediately after I start it on emulator.

I have another project with default setting as: empty project with actionbar. So I was trying to find out why by simply changing the activity to AppCompatActivity will  not work.

I think there is something wrong with the support library, so I added the android-support-v7-appcompat as a Referenced Libraries. However, the program still does not work.

```
package com.example.tracker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //get the button
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logcat:
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tracker/com.example.tracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.tracker.MainActivity
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 10:06:44.858: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/second" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The contens below are menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.tracker.MainActivity" 
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/myitem"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="myitem"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Hey can you please post your code? And since you are new to Android, why don't you start directly with Android Studio, because Eclipse and ADT are not supported anymore.

Comment: Thanks, my code is up. I am using eclipse because I heard that it is the standard. Is it still possible to use it?

Comment: @EdwardZ you can still use it, but you should really consider using Android Studio because Eclipse isn't supported anymore. You can import your existing projects to Android Studio if you want.

Comment: 1. Post your logcat exception. 2. Eclipse was standard year ago, Android Studio rocks!

Comment: "program does not work" is not a very clear description of the problem. Is it compilation error? Is it unhandled exception? Please edit your question..

Comment: Because I am using a book to learn Eclipse, I have not much confidence in using Android Studio. Does Android Studio has the same file components as in ADT of Eclipse?

Comment: If you want to learn Eclipse it's another story, but if you want to keep working on Android, you better use Android studio.

Comment: @Mood, thank you. But will most of the structures be the same?

Comment: Yes and with time you will find it even better.

Comment: @Lamorak, I have posted the first couple of lines of logcat. I have no idea what does this mean

Comment: check that your activity is using Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with your activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your activity to the Manifest.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.tracker.MainActivity"/>
```

If it's already there, try migrating to Android Studio because it might be an issue related to Eclipse, and the way it handles dependencies.

Comment: The whole thing is default, except I changed extends Activity to AppCompatActivity. Nothing else goes wrong  untill my change.

Comment: This, however, seems to be right. `ClassNotFoundException` often gets thrown when you don't have you activity added in manifest.

Comment: If I am having two activities, main activity uses AppCompatActivity, and the other use Activity. Would this be an issue?

Comment: imo your Manifest looks good, this leaves me suspecting Eclipse, and how it manages dependencies. Try to clean your project, or more over try Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export and check the support library.

Comment: @Mood I have tried the above suggestions, and there is a error observable, which is under res/menu/main.xml, which says:No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package

Comment: Well that's another question. try adding this <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"> and  app:showAsAction

Comment: @EdwardZ this is a new issue we can't discuss it in here, I'd be happy to help, but it will be better if you open a new question. Don't hesitate to put the link to the new question in here, so I can find it easily

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654664/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-showasaction-in-package