# No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package "..."

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was trying to modify an default empty activity and form a default activity with action bar. There are two activities I made, which are both empty without actionbar. What I try to achieve is to click on the first activity(without actionbar) and navigate to the second activity(with actionbar). What I have done are:
1. add a menu
2. modify the second activity by changing the activity to AppCompatActivity
3. add a support library which is v7-appcompat (which was added as a referenced library. I am not sure whether it should be referenced lib or other format.)
The Manifest file part is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/second" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The first activity is:

```
package com.example.tracker;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //get the button
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The second activity is:

```
package com.example.tracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The menu in res is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.tracker.MainActivity" 
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/myitem"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="myitem"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

The only observable problem is that the menu has an error which is written in the title of this problem. Currently, the first activity can run properly, however, when I click the button, the application stops.

By removing app:showAsAction="never" does not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you compiling your dependencies using gradle? Can you post your gradle build file?

Comment: @blackcj I don't think he is using gradle we've been discussing his issues on another feed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647391/change-activity-to-appcompatactivity-leads-to-program-failure-eclipseandroid/31650418#31650418

Comment: Maybe off-topic but I don't see why you should use `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)`. Try to remove this line.